# Запятая перед "и лишь"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед "и лишь":

> Кроме того, в течение мая в поселке произошло 12 ДТП, в результате транспортные средства получили повреждения и лишь по счастливой случайности обошлось без пострадавших.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужна ли запятая перед "и лишь"

Нужна. Разделяет части ССП.

**P.S.**

А после "ДТП" лучше, на мой взгляд, поставить точку:

*Кроме того, в течение мая в поселке произошло 12 ДТП. В результате...*